# A p adic limit of a binomial coefficient

Tags: co.combinatorics, algebraic-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, p-adic-analysis

Let $0 \leq a \leq p^n$ be a number coprime to p. Consider the following sequence of binomial coefficients:

$$B_k = \binom{p^{n+k}}{p^ka} $$
as $k\to \infty$. If I did the computation right, the p-adic valuation of $ B_k$ is finite and constant for $k$ large enough. This suggests that the limit exists p-adically, is this true? If so what is the limit and does it only depend on $a/p^n$?

Perhaps one can relate the limits with approximations obtained from the p-adic Gamma function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem tells you pretty much everything about the arithmetic of binomial coefficients

Comment: @SamHopkins: It helps only mod $p$. Higher powers require other tools. This one, however, should follow from the ghost-Witt structure (e.g., Lemma 19 in https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/witt5.pdf ). This shows that more generally, if $u$ and $v$ are any integers, then $\dbinom{p^k u}{p^k v}$ converges to a limit in $\mathbb Z_p$ when $k \to \infty$.

Comment: To show that the $p$-adic limit exists all you need is the congruence $$\binom{p^k u}{p^k v}\equiv \binom{p^{k-1}u}{p^{k-1}v} \pmod{p^k},$$ which is not hard to prove. (In fact this congruence holds modulo $p^{3k}$ for $p>3$, but we don't need this stronger congruence.)

Comment: Following up on Ira Gessel's comment, look up the Jacobstahl Kazandzidis congruence.

Comment: Isn't it true that the $p$-adic valuation of $B_k$ is $n$ since $p$ does not divide $a$?